# how to set v140_xp toolset in command prompt for build with NMake?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, nmake

I have some lib project that should be built with `nmake` makefiles for Windows XP.

How to change toolset in VS2015 Native Command Prompt from `v140` to `v140_xp` (Visual Studio 2015 - Windows XP (v140_xp)).
Any ideas ?

Comment: Toolsets only work if you use MSBuild to build.  Picking the right build tool executables, tool options and directories is entirely your job when you use NMake.  The v140_xp toolset uses SDK 7.1 and sets the linker's /SUBSYSTEM.  Only the SDK matters for library projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cmake knows how to compile for XP.

The trick is to add flags `-T v140_xp` to Cmake command-line, add directive `set( CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE on )` to CmakeLists.txt, let msbuild compile your code.

`cmake -T v140_xp path/to/src
msbuild host.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Release`

All compile and link flags will be output to terminal.

For older version of VisualStudio, use v120_xp instead of v140_xp

Comment: Thank you, the long-awaited answer!

Comment: This works only if you build with msbuild, not with nmake.